# Binding times for template variables

Tags: c++, binding

In C++ for a template T variable for a class.
What would it's binding time be?

I'm thinking compile time because it would need to know what value is being passed to it before binding it to a value/address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could think of templates as "class factories", the result of using a template is a class that has been specialized for the specific types you use in the template. So this is all compile-time specialization.